# Анимация html + css

Tags: html, css, css3

Блок с картинкой, в заданное время сменяется вторым блоком с картинкой и так бесконечно. Это возможно при помощи css и html?

Comment: Да, возможно...

Comment: Каким образом можете подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: @Qwertiy поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь, но это возможно для webkit, но не для всех браузеров.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation - это возможно для всех браузеров, кроме IE9- и полного старья (FF4-, Safari 3, Opera 11-). Даже в 12й Опере работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, просмотрел =) Действительно всё лучше, чем я думал

Comment: @Qwertiy, каким же образом скролить блоки? При наведении получается сделать горизонтальную анимацию, а хотелось бы что бы автоматически!? Подскажите пожалуйста если знаете.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: slides-10 10s steps(10) infinite;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}

@keyframes slides-10 {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to   { transform: translateX(-1000%); }
}
```

```html
<div style=background:red>
</div><div style=background:green>
</div><div style=background:silver>
</div><div style=background:blue>
</div><div style=background:orange>
</div><div style=background:white>
</div><div style=background:antiquewhite>
</div><div style=background:gray>
</div><div style=background:yellow>
</div><div style=background:margenta>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
@keyframes slide {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    50%   {left: 0;}
    51% {left: -300px;}
    100% {left: -300px;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container .container-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  width:610px;
  height:300px;
  left:0px;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.container .container-wrapper div:first-child {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://blogldc.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2015_07_17_LearnCSS.jpg');
}
.container .container-wrapper div:last-child{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://cdn.compsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Top-10-best-CSS-development-tools-2015.png');
}
```

html:

```
<div class = 'container'>
 <div class = 'container-wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/ap6m8c9n/2/) . Касательно поддержки animation в браузерах [animation support](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

Comment: Не кроссбраузерно, кажется. Надо блоки скроллить, а не фон менять.

Comment: речь о горизонтальной смене блока, а не о смене фона одного блока.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Теперь через прокрутку и кроссбраузерно. Спасибо за замечание!